# Using JQuery to disable a dropdown list reverts back immediately

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jQuery to disable a dropdownlist.  It's very strange -- when I add a breakpoint in firebug it works fine! However, if I just run it I see it get disabled for a fraction of a second and then get reenabled!

Basically:

I want to disable the list if ($("#MessageTypes").val() == 'Text To Speech')

Not sure why its not sticking..
If I take out the $.get line it works fine.
Why would that reset it? Especially since I disable the list after that code?

Thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function () {

    $("#MessageTypes").change(function () {

        var sMessageType = $("#MessageTypes").val();
        $.get('@Url.Action("GenerateMessageDesc")', { messageType: sMessageType }, function (data) { $('#MessageDesc').replaceWith(data); });

        //Text To Speech Chosen
        if ($("#MessageTypes").val() == 'Text To Speech') {
            $("#MessageDesc").val('5');  //5 is TEXT ID from database -- prob not best practice
            $("#MessageDesc").attr("disabled", true); //disable select
            $("#MessageContent").removeAttr("disabled"); //Enable Message Content
        }

    });
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$.ajax({
    data: ..., type: ..., url: ...,
    success: function(){ //disable here.. }
});
```

Or

```
$.get('@Url.Action("GenerateMessageDesc")', { messageType: sMessageType }, 
    function (data) { $('#MessageDesc').replaceWith(data);             
       //other necessary computations
       $("#MessageDesc").attr("disabled", true);})
```

This is an issue with synchronous v/s asynchronous execution. the lines after $.get continue executing without waiting for the response, unless it is a callback.

Comment: I moved the ;}) to encompass the entire call like you said and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

`$.get` is asynchronous, so it's firing its callback after the code to disable the option runs. You'll need to move that code into the callback.